# Date picker returning year 1970, no matter current year is selected by finger

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Datepicker saves the year 1970 no matter normal date is selected and saved.

If anyone has any clue what would be a solution to this problem I would appreciate it.

The program asking me to write more text altho i don't know what to write you more but i need to write something so it would actually let me post it so i appologize for this unneeded text .

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


Activity act;

TextView showDate;

long datelimit = 0;

long setDate = 0;

boolean checkToDate = false, isNoPast = false;

String devicePattern;

public DatePickerFragment(Activity act, TextView lblDate1, String setDate) {
    this.act = act;
    showDate = lblDate1;
    this.setDate = Long.valueOf(setDate);
    SimpleDateFormat deviceDateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(act.getApplicationContext());
    devicePattern = deviceDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
}

public DatePickerFragment(Activity act, TextView lblDate1, String startFrom, String setDate) {
    this.act = act;
    showDate = lblDate1;
    this.datelimit = Long.valueOf(startFrom);
    this.setDate = Long.valueOf(setDate);
    SimpleDateFormat deviceDateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(act.getApplicationContext());
    devicePattern = deviceDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
}

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

public DatePickerFragment(Activity act, EditText lblDate1, String startFrom, boolean checkToDate, String setDate) {
    this.act = act;
    showDate = lblDate1;
    this.datelimit = Long.valueOf(startFrom);
    this.checkToDate = checkToDate;
    this.setDate = Long.valueOf(setDate);
    SimpleDateFormat deviceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.APP_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
    devicePattern = deviceDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
}

public DatePickerFragment(Activity act, EditText lblDate1, String startFrom, boolean checkToDate, String setDate, boolean isNoPast) {
    this.act = act;
    showDate = lblDate1;
    this.datelimit = Long.valueOf(startFrom);
    this.checkToDate = checkToDate;
    this.setDate = Long.valueOf(setDate);
    this.isNoPast = isNoPast;
    SimpleDateFormat deviceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.APP_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
    devicePattern = deviceDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (setDate > 0)
        c.setTimeInMillis(setDate);
    else if (!checkToDate && datelimit > 0)
        c.setTimeInMillis(datelimit);
    final int myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (datelimit != 0)
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(datelimit);
    final int minYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int minMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int minDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, myear, mmonth, mday);
    if (isNoPast) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    }

    if (!checkToDate && datelimit > 0) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    } else if (checkToDate && datelimit > 0) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(myear, mmonth, mday, new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            if (checkToDate && datelimit != 0) {
                if (newDate.after(calendar)) {
                    view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                }
            } else if (!checkToDate && datelimit != 0) {
                /*Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                c1.setTimeInMillis(datelimit);
                Long date2 = c1.getTimeInMillis();
                view.init(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH), c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), this);*/
                if (newDate.before(calendar)) {
                    view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    /*if (checkToDate && datelimit != 0)
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(datelimit);
    else if (!checkToDate && datelimit != 0)
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(datelimit);*/

    datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
    datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    return datePickerDialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    Long date1 = c.getTimeInMillis();

    /*Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTimeInMillis(datelimit);
    Long date2 = c1.getTimeInMillis();

    if (datelimit > 0) {

        if (!checkToDate) {
            if (date1 < date2) {
                Toast.makeText(act, "To date should not be less than From date ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            *//*showDate.setTag(c1.getTimeInMillis());
            //int month = monthOfYear + 1;
            Date selectedDate = new Date(c1.getTimeInMillis());
            String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
            showDate.setText(finalDate);*//*
            } else {
                showDate.setTag(c.getTimeInMillis());
                //int month = monthOfYear + 1;
                Date selectedDate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
                String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
                showDate.setText(finalDate);
            }
        } else {
            showDate.setTag(c.getTimeInMillis());
            //int month = monthOfYear + 1;
            Date selectedDate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
            String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
            showDate.setText(finalDate);
        }

    } else {
        showDate.setTag(c.getTimeInMillis());
        //int month = monthOfYear + 1;
        Date selectedDate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
        String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
        showDate.setText(finalDate);
    }*/
    showDate.setTag(c.getTimeInMillis());
    //int month = monthOfYear + 1;
    Date selectedDate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
    showDate.setText(finalDate);

    //showDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    //showDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year+" "+CommonMembers.getDateTime(2));
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (setDate > 0) {
        showDate.setTag(setDate);
        Date selectedDate = new Date(setDate);
        String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat(devicePattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedDate);
        showDate.setText(finalDate);
    } else {
        showDate.setTag(null);
        showDate.setText("");
    }
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was date format , ive lost 3 days on this :(

Answer (score 0):

hmm, dialog fragment, must use no-arg constructor and use bundle along with setArguments to pass and use onCreate's bundle to get those value.

This is how you create an instance:

```
DatePickerFragment fragment = DatePickerFragment.getInstance(arg1, arg2).
```

---

```
 public static DatePickerFragment getInstance(String startFrom, String setDate) {
    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("startFrom", startFrom);
    args.putString("setDate", setDate);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: I can wait when you have time as I really don't understand where is a problem.

Comment: i still havent resolved i have no clue whats wrong with it